# Empty char array in Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

I am working on small project using Arduino. I have this char array which used to store some values. the problem is How to set this char array to null after assign some  values in Arduino?

```
char packetBuffer[200]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `memset` from `string.h`:

```
memset(packetBuffer, 0, sizeof packetBuffer);
```

Comment: what if I want to comapre the value of packetBuffer. for instance if it is equal to 'ON', print ON.

Comment: @JAMES Use `strcmp`, `strncmp` or `memcmp`, depending on whether your string is null-terminated or not.